# Why am I getting this output

Tags: python, list, loops

In the mentioned code I expect output as `0 1 2 3`, but I got an output which is `0 1 2 2`.Please help me why it is so? , how it is working.This is the code of my problem statement.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

This is code in python, output got is `0 1 2 2`

Comment: add `print(a)` to see that you change value on list which you use to get value. After first loop you have list `[0,1,2,0]`, after second loop you have `[0,1,2,1]`, etc. And before last loop you have `[0,1,2,2]` and when `for` gets last element from list then it is `2`, not `3`. In python better don't change list when you get values from list.

Comment: @David Buck, :) :) as I am new to StackOverflow, so I did not know; henceforth I will do for sure.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is this:

```
>>> for i in a:
...     a[-1] = i
...     print(a[-1])
... 
0
1
2
2
```

Its because a[-1] is assigned the value of next(iterable a) in a sense, at each loop.
`for` loop makes iterable, then calls next on that iterable, then it's assigned to the iteration variable.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you are reassigning the values inside your list whilst iterating over it. If you print out the entire list in your loop you will see the following:

```
>>> for a[-1] in a:
...   print(a)
...
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

If you want to go through individual items in your list you would have to name your variable a different way such as:

```
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

Output then is `0 1 2 3` as you would expect.